# prepareForSegue and popViewController compatibility

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

### The question

I'm working on a `iOS` app and i have 3 consecutive `ViewControllers`:

**`TableViewController` --> `DetailViewController` --> `ImageViewController`**

I perform de forward Segue with a button (Just control drag on `Storyboard`) and to go back I have a custom back button with

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To send data forward I use

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [segue.destinationViewController someFunction];
}
```

To send data to the parent `ViewController` I can use `prepareForSegue` in the `DetailViewController`, but it doesn't work in the `ImageViewController` and there I have to use `Notifications`.

**It's OK if I use `prepareForSegue` to send data with `popViewControllerAnimated`?**

**Should I use Notifications in both cases?**

### Some code

What I have in the `DetailViewController` is a button that perform the Segue to the ImageViewController (just control drag on `Storyboard`) and a Back Button with:

```
- (IBAction)backAction:(id)sender {
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and then the function:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"forwardSegue"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController someFuntionToImageViewController];
    } else {
        [segue.destinationViewController someFuntionToParentViewController];
    }
}
```

I noticed that I can't assign a segue.identifier to the `popViewController` action.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple recommends the following way to pass data between view controllers that are navigated by segues:

**To pass data forward**:

You declare a property on the destination vc and set its value in the `prepareForSegue` method. (So kind of the way you did it)

```
@interface SomeViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) VeryImportantData *data;
//...
@end

@implementation SourceVC

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    VeryImportantData *theData = ...;
    segue.destinationViewController.data = theData;
}
```

**To pass data back**

You declare a delegate protocol. This could look like this:

```
@protocol SomeViewControllerDelegate
- (void)someViewController:(SomeViewController *) someVC didFinishWithData:(SomeData *) data;
@end
```

Your destination vc provides a delegate property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SomeViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

The destination vc calls it's delegates method once it's ready to be closed:

```
@implementation SomeViewController

- (void) close
{
    [delegate someViewController:self didFinishWithData:self.data];
}
```

And your source controller implements the protocol and sets itself as delegate of the destination vc in the `prepareForSegue` method.

```
@implementation SourceVC

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    segue.destinationViewController.delegate = self;
}


//...
- (void)someViewController:(SomeViewController *) someVC didFinishWithData:(SomeData *) data
{
    self.receivedData = data;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

I'm not used with delegating...
Where do I have to write the protocol?

**Edit:**
OK, sorry, I have just read it.

Comment: It might be worth reading [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) lot's of great information about design patterns including delegation