# How to detect whether show (push) segue navigation controller is pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have two ViewControllers, first and second. They are connected with show (push) segue. I click button on firstViewController to go to secondViewController. Then using automatically added navigation controller `<First` , I go back to firstViewController. However, here I would like to get alert message when navigation controller to firstViewContoller is pressed. How do I do it?

Comment: Not quite clear on what you're asking, but maybe `prepareForSegue:` is what you are looking for.

Comment: What sort of "alert message"? Like a UIAlertView/UIAlertController?

Comment: On the secondViewController, navigation bar would look like this, `<First` on the top left corner. Then if I click this, I want to receive message saying, you clicked navigation controller to go back to firstViewController.

Comment: Gotcha. But then do you also want to perform the pop upon button press or do you just want to show the message?

Comment: @LyndseyScott, it doesn't matter, can be NSLog message saying I pressed the navigation controller on the top left corner to go back to firstViewController.

Comment: Then like @JackWu said, you can put an NSLog in prepareForSegue:

Comment: @JackWu can I use prepareForSegue on the secondViewController to go back to firstViewController? I tried multiple times but didn't work for me. I thought it always go forward not backward.

Comment: @LyndseyScott, so you mean for example, my show(push) segue is called "gotoSecond". Then use this name to go back to firstViewController.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I did this, it is not doing anything. It is added in secondViewController. Segue between first and secondViewController is called GotoSecondSegue.
`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GotoSecondSegue"]){
        
        NSLog(@"My segue to firstViewController is pressed");
    }
    
}`

Comment: `prepareForSegue` won't get called when going back. What *will* get called though, is the `- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;` callback in `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Try giving that a spin!

Comment: You've used two different identifiers: "goToSecond" and "GoToSecondSegue".

Comment: @LyndseyScott, sorry that was a mistake, my segue is called "GoToSecondSegue".

Comment: @LyndseyScott I'm fairly certain that `prepareForSegue` doesn't get called in this case. I believe the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` callback is the correct place here

Comment: @JackWu Yeah, you're probably right, but the docs aren't specific and many questions on stack overflow say the opposite (ex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13111038/2274694, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14144351/2274694), so I'm just going to try it for myself to double check...

Comment: @JackWu You're right. prepareForSegue isn't called. And hi on twitter! (I'm actually usually a good programmer and normally not such a nutcase. One of those days... Actually weeks. One of those weeks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work on the viewWillDisappear method on your second view controller like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.isMovingFromParentViewController){
        NSLog(@"Controller being popped");
    }
}
```

In this case, self.**isMovingFromParentViewController** will be true if the controller is being popped.

You can also check for self.**isMovingToParentViewController** on viewWillAppear for example, to check that the controller is being pushed.

Also self.**isBeingDismissed** and self.**isBeingPresented** are available and refer to when a controller is being presented/dismissed (modally).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

I believe the method that gives you the message you need is

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

And

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

In your CustomViewController, you are going to want to conform to the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol like this:

```
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

And then override the delegate methods above to get the messages you are looking for.

Here is an complete implementation in Swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        println(viewController)
    }
}

class FirstViewController: ViewController {
}

class SecondViewController: ViewController {
}
```